# GSAP timelineMax error, cannot read property 'repeat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm trying to create a simple timelineMax with GSAP and scrollMagic, I'm getting the following error. Everything looks right to me so I'm not understanding this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'repeat' of undefined
d.to @ TweenMax.min.js:14
(anonymous function) @ app.js:12
```

Line 12 is `.to("#parallax1 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone});` below.

Here's the code:

```
// init controller
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({globalSceneOptions: {triggerHook: "onEnter", duration: "200%"}});

    // build scenes
    // build tween1
    var tween1 = new TimelineMax();
        tween1.to("#parallax1 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone});   

    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#parallax1"})
                    .setTween(tween1)
                    .addIndicators()
                    .addTo(controller);
```

(I know there's no duration param in that tween, but if you look at http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/advanced/parallax_sections.html you can see that there's no duration parameter on their setTween and it works just fine).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the **duration** parameter:

`TweenMax.to(element, duration, {property: value});`.

Comment: Hi Tahir, I know it would seem that way, but if you look at http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/advanced/parallax_sections.html you can see that there's no duration parameter on their  `setTween`  and it works just fine   `.setTween("#parallax1 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone})` .  What's the difference between this and timelineMax? Does timelineMax always need a duration param?

Comment: Tahir, from the documentation it looks like you're right, missing the tween duration on .setTween is only a shorthand for a 1 second duration, and maybe this shorthand does not work on TimelineMax. Hmmm... 
`// short hand to add a TweenMax.to() tween for 1 second
// this is useful, when the scene has a duration and the tween duration isn't important anyway
scene.setTween("obj3", {y: 100});`  [Reference Link]( http://scrollmagic.io/docs/animation.GSAP.html#Scene.setTween)  Anyhow it's now working after adding a duration param. I wonder how I can get better error messages?

Comment: Can anyone explain what this selector means `parallax1 > div` ? What's the `<` in there all about?

Comment: Yup, as you have figured out, `setTween` is a utility provided by `ScrollMagic` with an option of omitting the `duration` parameter entirely. [[Link](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/docs/animation.GSAP.html#Scene.setTween)]. And yes `TweenMax` / `TweenLite` / `TimelineLite` / `TimelineMax` all of them need a `duration` value to work with. [[Link](https://ihatetomatoes.net/greensock-cheat-sheet/)] and [[Link](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/)].

Comment: `>` in selectors meaning direct descendant and there are many types of css selectors available. [[Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)], [[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)], [[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)], [[Link](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/)] & [[Link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/selectors.html#child-selector)].